# attempt to call 'addEventListener' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i have created some object using display.newRoundRect() in createScene function then in enterScene call i call this function

```
function generate_bonus_star()
  tiles = {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, B1, B2, B5, B6, C1, C6,
    D1, D6, E1, E2, E5, E6, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6}

  math. randomseed(os.clock())
  index = math.random(1,23)
  index_bonus_score = math.random(1,23)
  print("bonus star generated at "..index)
  print("bonus score generated at "..index_bonus_score)
end
```

**Note:** A1, A2..... are my object created using display.newRoundRect()

So in enterscene i added addEventListener of these. But i get the error "attempt to call method 'addEventListener' (a nil value)  on this line of code

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
  storyboard.purgeScene("levels")--remove previuos screens
  storyboard.purgeScene("level2result")
  generate_bonus_star()

  A1:addEventListener( "touch", simple(A1) )--event listeners
  A2:addEventListener( "touch", simple(A2) )
  A3:addEventListener( "touch", simple(A3) )
.
.
.
.
      tiles[index]:addEventListener( "touch", bonus_star ) //line 503
      tiles[index_bonus_score]:addEventListener( "touch", bonus_score )
```

**EDIT**
i have notice that i didn't get this error when i run it first time i get it second, third, or four time

Comment: can you print the exact traceback? and show the code that loops over index

Answer (score 0):

Second argumet of addEventLister may be null.

```
simple(A1)
```

is appeared sololy (without definition) in you code.

Comment: I am facing at this line of code tiles[index]:addEventListener( "touch", bonus_star ) and i have function simple in my code too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't set/run the tiles table before your tiles get created. 
You are running `generate_bonus_star()` before your objects creation which is impossible. To make everything work, just move your `generate_bonus_star()` below the creation of all objects.

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
  storyboard.purgeScene("levels")--remove previuos screens
  storyboard.purgeScene("level2result")
  -- generate_bonus_star() this shouldn't be here.

  A1:addEventListener( "touch", simple(A1) )--event listeners
  A2:addEventListener( "touch", simple(A2) )
  A3:addEventListener( "touch", simple(A3) )

  ...
  ...
  -- After all objects are created (A1, A2 ... F5, F6)
  generate_bonus_star()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but this is still not working

Comment: @user2934930 Try to do some debugs, try to `print` your value, or `print(type(tiles[index]))` and see what it is. Your tile might be a `nil` object. If you have a nil object on tiles tab, try to check first using: `if tiles[index] then` and do code inside this block. Remember, I'm talking about your error line, put these upside your error line.

Comment: i did a check on nil but it's okay i have a valid reference all the time

Comment: @user2934930 Make sure you have run a garbage collect each time you run the app. You might be not closing and running the app again, so It's recommended to always close your app and run again after each test/implementation. There's no problem with that, Your app won't get run twice on smartphones, and there's no way to run two instance of a game at the same time using a smartphone. So what recommended is to close/refresh/restart your game player/debugged after each time you want to write a code or test something.

Comment: actually i am debugging app using corona simulator but when i run this app on real device it didn't crash but get hang in next scene

Comment: @user2934930 The last remaining choice for you is to use: `if not tiles[index].addEventListener then continue end` If you're using a for loop.

Comment: @user2934930 Also take a note that you might be having a different kind of object in your tiles that might be not having the `addEventListener` function. print your `index` value and check it with your tiles, get the `type` of that index and check the API documentation of corona to see if the object has the `addEventListener` function or not.